# 19 simple tables giving "TeX capacity exceeded" / "Too many unprocessed floats"?

Tags: floats

When I added a couple of rather unremarkable tables to my document, it stopped compiling (using `pdflatex`):

*"TeX capacity exceeded (main memory)"*

I searched the web a bit (well, actually, mostly tex.SE), and found mention that using `lualatex` should avoid memory issues. So I tried running the code with `lualatex`, and got

*"Too many unprocessed floats"*

So, I tried to come up with a minimal working example, and was surprised to find that this little bit of code was sufficient to trigger the problem:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}\begin{tabular}{|c|}Foo\\\end{tabular}\end{table*}
\begin{table*}\begin{tabular}{|c|}Foo\\\end{tabular}\end{table*}
\begin{table*}\begin{tabular}{|c|}Foo\\\end{tabular}\end{table*}
\begin{table*}\begin{tabular}{|c|}Foo\\\end{tabular}\end{table*}
\begin{table*}\begin{tabular}{|c|}Foo\\\end{tabular}\end{table*}
\begin{table*}\begin{tabular}{|c|}Foo\\\end{tabular}\end{table*}
\begin{table*}\begin{tabular}{|c|}Foo\\\end{tabular}\end{table*}
\begin{table*}\begin{tabular}{|c|}Foo\\\end{tabular}\end{table*}
\begin{table*}\begin{tabular}{|c|}Foo\\\end{tabular}\end{table*}
\begin{table*}\begin{tabular}{|c|}Foo\\\end{tabular}\end{table*}
\begin{table*}\begin{tabular}{|c|}Foo\\\end{tabular}\end{table*}
\begin{table*}\begin{tabular}{|c|}Foo\\\end{tabular}\end{table*}
\begin{table*}\begin{tabular}{|c|}Foo\\\end{tabular}\end{table*}
\begin{table*}\begin{tabular}{|c|}Foo\\\end{tabular}\end{table*}
\begin{table*}\begin{tabular}{|c|}Foo\\\end{tabular}\end{table*}
\begin{table*}\begin{tabular}{|c|}Foo\\\end{tabular}\end{table*}
\begin{table*}\begin{tabular}{|c|}Foo\\\end{tabular}\end{table*}
\begin{table*}\begin{tabular}{|c|}Foo\\\end{tabular}\end{table*}
\begin{table*}\begin{tabular}{|c|}Foo\\\end{tabular}\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Apparently, I am missing something essential here, as 19 "simple" tables shouldn't be bringing LaTeX down...?!?

Comment: There is an entry in the TeX FAQ about `too many unprocessed floats`: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=tmupfl

Comment: It seems that you don't need `babel` nor `fontenc` in the MWE. The MWE should also be complete for a simpler document class such as `article`.

Comment: @N.N.: "Minimal" as in "lines of code", and I don't think two or three lines make that much of a difference. You know, I didn't encounter that problem in the lab, but in a real document (with >100 lines per table, auto-generated by a Perl script from real-world data files), and any solution that would not *also* work in strbook using ngerman babel and T1 fontenc wouldn't float my boat.

Comment: @DevSolar http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that/1098#1098 reads '"*minimal*" in *minimal working example* means that the document should not contain *any* (yes any!) code which isn't related to the error. If a code line can be removed without changing the error/issue it doesn't belong into the example. If a non-standard class is used for the original document and the error/issue still happens *with* a standard class then a standard class should be substituted.' Also, minimalism contributes to generality.

Comment: @N.N.: I humbly beg your pardon for missing your code-golf requirements. I also apologize a thousandfold for adding vertical whitespace that does not contribute to reproducing the problem.

Comment: @DevSolar: It is not *code-golf*.  It is to maximise the chance of you getting an answer.  Whilst this case is a mild example, we often have situations where people post vast swathes of code, including many, many unnecessary packages.  Then figuring out which package (or combination of packages) actually led to the error is a tedious task which is better done by the *questioner* than the *answerer*.  As I said, this case is mild but it may be that someone else with this problem comes across your post and thinks it not relevant because they're not using babel, fontenc, or scrbook.

Comment: (ctd) if you have specific requirements on the solution ("Must be compatible with scrbook") then those are best said in accompanying text.  Having them in the example code is not equivalent since it isn't clear that you have to use scrbook just from looking at your code: you do use it, but you don't say you have to.  So keeping your code minimal and your explanation full (but not excessively verbose!) makes it easier to understand both the problem and what form the solution has to take, making it easier to answer the question.

Comment: @DevSolar What I meant with "minimalism contributes to generality" is that having only lines of codes in the example that matters for the error makes it more general and then it might apply to and help more future visitors than if it's more specific.

Comment: Sorry, I went a bit overboard. But I ran into the problem in a project of 20,000+ lines spread over 50+ files, with `tabularx` tables 22 columns wide and 100+ rows long using some serious layouting, generated by a Perl script and included using `\input`, with 25+ packages in the preamble. I reduced it to the above example, and am chided for *verbosity* because of the document class and two extra lines? Next thing you accuse me for `{|c|}`, `Foo` and `table*` instead of `{c}`, `x` and `table`, and for not making the 19 tables into a macro called in a loop. (continued...)

Comment: (...) I am a software engineer of some experience, and I *do* understand the call for "minimal" examples, but this is really pushing it, which is why I called your demands "code golf". (end)

Comment: Someone said code golf? `\documentclass{book}\def\x{\begin{table}\end{table}}\def\y{\x\x}\begin{document}\y\y\y\y\y\y\y\y\y\y\end{document}`. But someone can certainly do better using more packages and/or `for` loops.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the command `\clearpage`. This prints all floats that are not yet placed and starts a new page.

Comment: This, indeed, solved the problem. In the actual document I am working on, the `table*`'s I added are full-page anyway, so `\clearpage` is a clean solution.

Comment: As egreg points out in his answer the problem is related to the positioning of the tables. My usual approach is to use the `afterpage` package to do something like `\afterpage{\clearpage}` to control the placement of big tables and figures. I usually go for filling the right page in a `twoside` document leaving a page of text on the left and a page floats on the right on a spread.

Comment: +1 I was thinking I have had this problem and now how did I solve it again... but this was it.

Answer (score 18):

Each float is pushed in a queue, which is capable to contain only 18 objects (allocated as boxes `\bx@A` to `\bx@R`).

This may be extended: the package **[morefloats](http://ctan.org/pkg/morefloats)** was written just for this. However the error "Too many unprocessed floats" is usually caused by too strict limits on float positioning: a table specified with

```
\begin{table}[!h]
```

and which can't be placed "there" will block all subsequent floats until coming to a `\clearpage` command (maybe issued by `\chapter`) or the end of the document. If 18 floats follow it, the error will be issued.

Comment: Of course one immediately begins to wonder: "Why eighteen?!" And it turns out that 18 one-line tables with 10 point Computer Modern using article.cls produces *almost exactly* one page worth of material.

Comment: @kahen Nice remark, never thought about that.

Answer (score 2):

From LaTeX 2015/10/01 onwards the default size of the float queue is raised from 18 to 52. Also it may be made larger (several thousand) using the command `\extrafloats` added in the 2015/01/01 release.

Despite the above, egreg's answer is still valid, if the float options or constraints are preventing good float placement, having a longer float queue means it just takes longer to be told that floats can not be placed.