# Table generating error

Tags: tables, floats

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [19 simple tables giving “TeX capacity exceeded” / “Too many unprocessed floats”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/19-simple-tables-giving-tex-capacity-exceeded-too-many-unprocessed-floats)

TexStudio 2.3 Miktex2.9

Hi everybody I am kind if new to LaTeX. I get stuck with a table. (I am also new in this web page too, If I am posting in a wrong place, or explaining my situation in a wrong way let me know)

the problematic part of my code

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{
\bf{Table title }}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{l|lllll|}
\cline{2-6}
 & Marginal  & Marginal  & Marginal  & Error In  & Computation  \\ 
 & Distribution of  & Distribution of  & Distribution of  & overal  & time  \\ 
 & Protein 1 & Protein 2 & Protein 3 & distribution pi &  \\ 
\cline{2-6}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ 
\cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{New Method} &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Norm 1 Error} & 0.00021535 & 0.00039544 & 0.00039173 & 0.000759 & 191.374765 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Norm 2 Error} & 0.00006730 & 0.00018785 & 0.00014481 & 0.000050 &  \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Mean value error} & 0.00089788 & 0.00290000 & 0.00400000 &  &  \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ 
\cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Gillespie Algorithm (1000 runs)} &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Norm 1 Error} & 0.19940000 & 0.13650000 & 0.14260000 & 0.726400 & 315.319292 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Norm 2 Error} & 0.07780000 & 0.04120000 & 0.06320000 & 0.034200 &  \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Mean value error} & 1.58060000 & 1.02980000 & 0.82270000 &  &  \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ 
\cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Gillespie Algorithm (10000 runs)} &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Norm 1 Error} & 0.15970000 & 0.13630000 & 0.24140000 & 0.481700 & 2821.549582 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Norm 2 Error} & 0.06110000 & 0.05720000 & 0.09330000 & 0.026800 &  \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Mean value error} & 1.56420000 & 0.07170000 & 0.32480000 &  &  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\begin{flushleft} Errors and calculation times for new method and Gillespie algorithm for oscillatory system: All the errors are measured with respect to traditional algorithm.  New method is much more precise compared to all the other algorithms. All calculations are done by MATLAB R2012a
\end{flushleft}
\label{table: Oscillatory Error}
\end{table}
```

the error that I am taking

```
Too many unprocessed floats. \begin{table}[!ht]
Missing number, treated as zero \end{table}
Missing number, treated as zero \end{table}
Undefined control sequence
Paragraph ended before \@xnext was complete \end{table}
You can't use `\vadjust' in vertical mode \end{table}
Argument of \@xnext has an extra }
Float(s) lost.
```

I really do not understand anything about the situation.

Comment: Hi and welcome. You can format code by selecting it and clicking on the {} icon.  One thing you could have done is searched on the site for "too many unprocessed floats". There are a number of similar questions to yours here.  Here's one: [19 simple tables giving “TeX capacity exceeded” / “Too many unprocessed floats”?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35593)/2693. This should have a solution to your problem.