# externalizing the caption together with legend

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following plot:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 scale only axis,
width = 0.8\columnwidth,
height = 0.8\columnwidth,
enlargelimits = 0.15,
xlabel = {\# Classes loaded},
xlabel style = {
at = {(1,0)},
anchor = south east
},
ylabel = {\# Methods called},
ylabel style = {
at = {(0,1)},
anchor = north west,
rotate = -90
},
ticklabel style = {/pgf/number format/fixed},
cycle list = {
{black, fill=black!50, mark=square*},
{black, fill=black!100, mark=*},
{black, fill=black!100, mark=o},
{black, fill=black!100, mark=triangle},
}]
\addplot+[only marks] coordinates {
(251, 839) 
(172, 463) 
(174, 467) 
(269, 958) 
(206, 639) 
(180, 515) 
(209, 641) 
(225, 623) 
(208, 605) 
(329, 1227) 
};
\label{pgfplots:java}
\addplot+[only marks] coordinates {
(4286, 11546) 
(4277, 11384) 
(4295, 11632) 
(4313, 11726) 
(4251, 11250) 
(4311, 11851) 
(4321, 11714) 
(4260, 11381) 
(4261, 11304) 
(4323, 11866) 
};
\label{pgfplots:jruby}
\addplot+[only marks] coordinates {
(1781, 5128) 
(1777, 5119) 
(1740, 4892) 
(1813, 5377) 
(1780, 5123) 
(2107, 6052)
(1778, 5135) 
(1745, 4995) 
(1719, 4826) 
(1749, 5031) 
};
\label{pgfplots:clojure}

\addplot+[only marks] coordinates {
(2726, 7663) 
(2701, 7576)
(2881, 7917)
(2761, 7788)
(2211, 6298)
(2799, 7872)
(2747, 7876)
(2147, 6053) 
(2789, 7844) 
(2719, 7753) 
};
\label{pgfplots:jython}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Number of classes loaded and methods called at least once by the Clojure~(\ref{pgfplots:clojure}), Java~(\ref{pgfplots:java}), JRuby~(\ref{pgfplots:jruby}), and Jython~(\ref{pgfplots:jython})   benchmarks.}
\end{figure}
```

which produces the following chart: 
[image]

I have plenty of those in my paper and latex gives an error: LaTeX Error: Too many unprocessed floats..., therefore I've decided to externalize them. Now the question is how to externalize the caption together with the legend. All my legends are stored in captions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you take a look at [pgfplots: externalization and legend referencing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37471/pgfplots-externalization-and-legend-referencing) and check whether that solves your problem?

Comment: The problem "too many unprocessed floats is entirely unrelated to tikz/pgfplots. In fact, you would have the same problem with externalized images. Perhaps you should pose a new question "How do I avoid too many unprocessed floats?" (I am only aware of `\clearpage` somewhere in the document). That said, external images have a worth on their own, so the question might be of interest to you anyway.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/19-simple-tables-giving-tex-capacity-exceeded-too-many-unprocessed-floats and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46512/too-many-unprocessed-floats